# Unity grids: individual GameObjects for each cell vs. Mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, grid, mesh

I'm new to Unity and I'm trying to implement a Sims-like room customization. I need a grid of squares, on which to place objects. I would also like to show the grid lines.

I've looked around the web and these are the possible approaches I found:

1. Each grid cell is an individual GameObject (plane). Easy to implement with two nested **for** cycles. Grid lines can be shown easily, since each tile can be textured individually.
2. The grid is one single plane. A mesh is rendered over the plane. This is probably a more efficient approach than the above one, but how do I display the grid lines texture?
3. The game is in 3D, but we can look at the room floor in 2D space. I'm wondering if it's a good idea to pretty much have a two-dimensional array of all of the tiles and calculate the coordinates of each tile. I won't even need a texture for the grid lines - they can be drawn over the plane, since I will know all of the coordinates needed.

First approach seems costly, but it's very popular on the web. The second approach is advertised as more efficient, but I'm having doubts that this might be an overkill for me, since I won't have terrain bumps and such. Third approach - I didn't see much on the Internet about it, but I have used it in old 2D OpenGL projects of mine.

I'm trying to figure out what is the "Unity way" to do this. A lot of people have mentioned the second approach on the web, but almost no one seems to have spoken of the third one.

I'd be thankful if someone provided some insight on this.

Comment: Considering the number of squares, I doubt there would be much difference

Comment: For the second and third approaches, you mean? Or for all 3? For now, I probably won't have more than 200 tiles in a grid or so, but if I follow the first approach, 200 GameObjects seem like a lot.

Comment: All 3.  It's a low-dimension grid matrix so even though 1) might result in more draw calls, it might not be significant in the scheme of things.  2) probably has the least draw calls.  Might be best to benchmark it

Comment: If it's just to indicate the existence of an underlying grid model, can't you just use a projector?

Comment: @Bart You mean use a projector to highlight cells? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "underlying grid model", could you elaborate? As I understand it, I need to build a grid model myself. My problem is that I can't decide which approach is most convenient.